# create temp table from join contained + 65 milion of records Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables, create-table

I am using Mysql I have two tables to which i am doing multiple selects during proc run, each of them is more tan 100 milion records, to speed up proc i want to do this join ones have it as temp table (contains 65+ milion of records), later use this table in procedure . to create it . iam using . next .

```
   create temporary table T_join (INDEX(tm_id))
    SELECT 
        t1.id,
        t2.tm_id,
        t1.code,
        t1.bincode,
        t1.AU,
        t1.TA,
        t2.fin_amount,
        t2.m_id
    FROM
        pm_customers t1
            INNER JOIN
       client_transactions_final t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

all straight forward the only problem to create this temp table proc spend more than 20 minutes, how to speed up it ?

Comment: Well, you have to bite the bullet somewhere.  Once you have paid the penalty of waiting 20 minutes (and also sacrificed some memory space), you have an indexed temp table which you can use to make everything else faster.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I know, but I am not sure if it will even finish in 20 min  :)  it  may take longer, so I am trying to find solution to reduce running  time

Comment: the view sounds like its roughly 65% of the data...how is this better than 2 full table scans (it's probably going to do that)...its hard to recommend something without seeing the procedure though

Comment: @Ctznkane525 with view . its bad i dea because i cannot create Index on it, and again its going to be same joins between two heavy tables all the time i will call that view

Comment: Will it be faster if you change the index to primary key for the temp table? Based on how primary key and  index works

Comment: @Jacob I am afraid I cant  because it may have duplicates for tm_id

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen said, you have to bite the bullet somewhere. At this time, 20 minutes is that cost.
Along with your procedure, can you please say the hardware and storage environment for your database?

Comment: @DavidButtrick I am using aws db.t2.large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT c.id, ct.tm_id, c.code, t1.bincode, c.AU, c.TA,
       ct.fin_amount, ct.m_id
FROM pm_customers c INNER JOIN
     client_transactions_final ct
     ON c.id = ct.id;
```

You probably want an index on `client_transactions_final(id, tm_id, fin_amount, m_id)`.  This is a covering index for the query, so this should improve performance.

I'm not convinced that you really need to create this temporary tables.  With the right indexes, join's are usually pretty fast.  Temporary tables make more sense when you have aggregations and more complex queries.  I'm not saying it won't work, just that it is not the first solution that would come to mind.

Comment: I just see no point doing this join 7 times during proc run because pm_customers has 130 000 000 records , client_transactions_final 996 000 000 records,  it is inconvenient to do same join all the time